# Как вытащить рассписание(Exel file) из сайта

Tags: парсер

У меня есть рассписание занятий, которое выкладывают каждый день в какое-то время. Как можно сделать так что бы как только это рассписание появится, оно пришло ко мне куда-то(почта, телеграм и т.д)
На каком языке программирования это можно сделать ? Мне бы начальную инструкцию

Comment: в предполагаемом интервале времени, когда ожидается появление расписания надо в цикле ходить на сайт и проверять файл. Если имя файла постоянное, то просто забирать файл сразу. Если имена файлов разные, то вытаскивать с сайта ссылку на него и вторым шагом уже тащить файл. Далее верифицировать, что файл действительно новый, а не вчерашний. Можно также попробовать ориентироваться на заголовки `last-modifed`. Далее цикл на эти стуки можно прервать и отправить файл куда надо. Сделать можно на любом языке в разумных пределах